# What is hd0 and sda/sdb in Linux?

Tags: linux, grub, mbr

I'm completely new to Linux, and am using Ubuntu 10.04.

I'm confused when to use what `(hdx,y)` to represent which hard drive.

I have 2 hard drives, the first one is identified as /dev/sda (in Disk Utility) and that's where I installed my old Windows 7 RC (unused). the second one is /dev/sdb where I installed my Ubuntu (in /dev/sdb7 and /dev/sdb8 swap) and XP (in /dev/sdb1).

now if I want to play around with Ubuntu's GRUB, what `(hdx,y)` should I use?
For now, I want to install BURG, and I read the installation step in a website that I have to type `burg-install "(hd0)"` to install BURG to the hd's MBR, but I'm just unsure, I'm afraid it'll mess everything.

So, how can I know which harddisk is (hd0), (hd1), or (hd0,1), etc.?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When GRUB probes devices it makes a **device.map** file, you can find this in the same directory as your **grub.conf**. It will look similar to this:

```
(fd0)   /dev/fd0
(hd0)   /dev/sda
(hd1)   /dev/sdb
(hd2)   /dev/sdc
```

You are free to modify this as you see fit any time. Read more [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Device-map.html).

**UPDATE (Oct. 21, 2015)** : This answer was originally written for GRUB 0.9x which is not under active development and is now referred to as GRUB Legacy. If you are using a version of GRUB 2.x you want [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Device-map.html) with details and advice on device mapping.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that

```
sda = hd0, 
sdb = hd1,
```

so on etc. etc. `sdc = hd2`
When it says `sda1` that would be `(hd0, 0)` and `sda2 (hd0, 1)` and `sda3 (hd0, 2)` and `sdb1 (hd1, 0)` so on and so forth...

Comment: In grub2, while this may be the "general rule to thumb", it's not always the case.  I'm currently trying to track down why my machine does not have the relationship you're talking about:

`[root@shooster ~]# cat /boot/grub2/device.map`

`(hd0)      /dev/sdb`

Answer (score 1):

grub does not make any difference between scsi and ide devices in its naming convention. the difference is only at the operating system level.
Infact if you go to the grub command-line mode, you will be able to try the devices available by tabbing.
refer this article for a [nice grub tutorial](http://slashroot.in/linux-grubgrand-unified-bootloader-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo grub-mkdevicemap
sudo cat /boot/grub/device.map
```

will show you something like this:

```
(hd0)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_500GB_S21JNXAG900082K
(hd1)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_120GB_S21UNXAH101068L
(hd2)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-08M2NA0_WD-WCC3F3579300
```

```
ls /dev/disk/by-id -lt
```

will show something like this (and more):

```
ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_500GB_S21JNXAG900082K -> ../../sda
ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_120GB_S21UNXAH101068L -> ../../sdb
ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-08M2NA0_WD-WCC3F3579300 -> ../../sdc
```

Now you know for sure: hd0 = sda, hd1 = sdb, hd2 = sdc.

Answer (score 0):

Grub device names can be confusing, but you can use the linux device name and let grub figure it out. Like this:

```
burg-install /dev/sda
```